# Why did IDEA compile an error when opening the Chinese folder

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When compiling the program with IDEA, if you put the project in the folder in English, there will be no errors; if you put the project in the folder in Chinese, there will be compilation errors.
Why is that？（just wanted to ask the technical question）

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is having an issue understanding the characters in the file's path or is breaking up the file path due to whitespace in the text.

example if path is:
    C:/user/john doe/documents/file

the space in john doe causes some weird error. like it considers it a new line or something not entirely sure. But had this error before.

could be similar with not being able to interpret the name of your folder